What type of relationship should I have between these two classes (tables)?
I'm trying to figure out what type of relationship should I make for these two tables, where one appointment have one user for client and other user for employee. Also, a user can be employee at one time and client at another time.
I'm using PHP 8.1, MYSQL, Symfony and Doctrine for this small project.
Tnahks.

#[ORM\Entity()]
#[ORM\Table(name: "appointments")]
class Appointments
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    private int $id;

    private User $employee;

    private User $client;
}

#[ORM\Entity()]
#[ORM\Table(name: "user")]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "string")]
    private string $name;
}


I would just only have a single private User $user; in the Appointments class. Keep it simple. If the distinction between a "client" and an "employee" is needed for an appointment, you could add a property for that. Something like private string $appointmentType;. But really, you question isn't very clear.

'I'm trying to figure out' - why ? That's a business rule, It's really up to you. You should at least have fk checks to users, But if you need to query how many appointments per employee (for example) you need to be able to distinguish employees from other types of user.

I agree with @P.Salmon, this is a business logic question, not a programming one. It seems from your description that you have 2x 1:n relationship between users and appointments tables.

Okay, let me make it clearer. I'll give you an example. I'm a dentist and I work with three other dentists. We have clients. When an appointment is made, it is made by one client with one dentist (we have an appointment). But if a dentist wants to make an appointment with a colleague, he also becomes a client. For this, in the Appointments table I have two fields, client and employee. Is that clearer?
So my question is how to make the relationship between the two tables so that I don't have a separate table for clients and a separate one for dentists.

You still haven't made clear why your appointment table can't simple have a single user and call it a client. You can indicate in the user table whether an user is a dentist or not, so if that information ever becomes relevant it is available.

I understand what you're saying, but my question was specifically, if I want to do it my way, what should be the relationship between the tables. Otherwise, thanks for the suggestion, maybe I'll do it that way. But I'm still curious how it would be done my way.
Thanks again.

Didn't Shadow already answer that question? You seem to want to create two "one-to-many" relationships to the same table, where only one relationship will actually be used at any one time. A very unusual way of doing things. This will complicate your database queries quite a lot.

Yes, I saw it now. Thanks a lot for your help.
